# multi instance of workflow wcf in memory

Tags: wcf, workflow

I Designed two WCF long running workflow (long life) with the names 'WCF A' and 'WCF B'.

I have a loop in 'WCF A'  , I'm sending a message to 'WCF B' in per execution of this loop. So it might exist some instances of 'WCF B' in memory until 'WCF B' got stop Message. Both WCF A and B are hosted in windows service. At first with executing Windows service everything is ok but after some time they will not work and as I monitored in Task manager they don't using any cpu usage.

Where is the problem from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends, monitoring cpu usage does not tell anything. It could be:

1. deadlock happened somewhere in your loop, i.e. maybe each instance use shared objects?
2. channel gets faulted (because time outs, exceptions etc) that execution cannot go through.
3. depends on what object of each instance of WCF B holds, it might reached OS limit, (for example: number of opened file)

From your question I am guess you may find debugging services are difficult, you could try following:

1. enable WCF logging , there are plenty entries on SO or google
2. attach debugger to your service, if you find this gives you random entry point, you can try put Debugger.Launch() call at OnStart overload of your service
3. log to file where your call up to
4. start your service as console application

hope this helps.